# Why does an emulator screen turn black when I move it from one computer screen to another?

Tags: android, android-emulator, screen

Situation:
Android BumbleBee
Running any of my emulator devices Pixel 3, Pixel 4, Pixel Tablet, etc. (device is ONLINE)
MacBook Pro ( most bells and whistles)
MacBook screen 17", 27" Dell screen, 25" HP screen

When I start an emulator, it will always open on the MacBook screen (17"). I had to give a Demo of our app and wanted to show on the 27" screen along with 3 other devices. The 17' screen isn't big enough so I moved them to the 27".

Moving the emulator with the mouse will put it in the bigger screen, but will show black. It is much like the hide android will do when you have a password or pin # screen available. I know the emulator is showing the correct thing because I can do a snapshot and the snapshot is correct. I just cannot see it because it is now black.

Moving the emulator back to the MacBook screen will show the emulated screen again.

I have tried to move it to a new screen and close it. Then open it again and Android will open on that screen but will do so blacked out. Moving it back to the Mac screen will again show the screen so I can see it.

At present, the only way I can see the emulated device on my big screen is if I load it through Vysor.

Has any one else experienced this? Why does Android make the screen black on an emulated device when I move it? If the only way I can see it is through Vysor, doesn't that defeat the purpose of an emulator? How do I fix this and see my emulator on the big screen?

Comment: have yuo tried with a non google play enabled emulator

Comment: yes both types of emulators will do the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With further investigation, I found that on a PC, through my docking station, the emulator screen stays visible on any screen.

Talking to a couple MacBook guys, they recommended reassigning the "main screen" to one of my external screens (and away from the Mac screen). This was the answer. By calling one(either one) of my external screens as primary or main screen, the emulator is visible on all screens.

Thanks to anyone that looked and tried to help out.